# ¿Cómo hacer que mi botón sticky se active/muestre a mitad de página?

Tags: javascript, html, botón, sticky

Ahora mismo tengo un botón de tipo **sticky** que se activa con el primer scroll, y necesito que se active en el terer scroll o al 50% de la página mostrada. A continuación copio mi código en su estado actual.

```js
var todossticky = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

todossticky.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div id="stickyHome" class="sticky-container"><div class="button-primary-sticky content-item "><a id="a" href="#ancla1" target="_self" aria-label="Ver" title="Ver">Ver</a></div></div>');
todossticky.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<style>.button-primary-sticky {    background-color: orange;border-color: orange;color: white;-webkit-text-fill-color: white; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;box-sizing: border-box; min-height: 44px; line-height: 28px; font-family: Verdana; min-width: 128px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid transparent; color: orange; -webkit-text-fill-color: orange; transition: background-color 0.2s ease; cursor: pointer;} .button-primary-sticky a{color:white; text-decoration:none;} #stickyHome.sticky-container.visible {bottom: 0px; } #stickyHome.sticky-container {position: fixed; z-index: 100; background: #FFF; width: 100%; padding: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; right: 0px; bottom: -60px; height: auto; transition: 0.2s ease; box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);}@media (min-width: 768px){#stickyHome.sticky-container {display: none;}}</style>');

let lastScrollY = 0, stickyHomeDisplayed = false;
  
function showStickyHome() {
  window.document.getElementById('stickyHome').classList.toggle('visible');
  stickyHomeDisplayed = !stickyHomeDisplayed;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  lastScrollY = window.scrollY;

  if (window.scrollY > 0 && !stickyHomeDisplayed) {
    requestAnimationFrame(showStickyHome);
  }
  else if (stickyHomeDisplayed && window.scrollY === 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(showStickyHome);
  }
}, { passive: true });
```

```html
<div style="height:2500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Puedes poner también el html? sino será imposible comprobarlo tal y como lo tienes

Comment: Ya he actualizado el código, funciona sobre cualquier div, basta con pasarlo pro consola, pero ahora funcionará haciendo scroll al ejecutar. Gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda :)

Comment: Me gusta lo limpio que te ha quedado. Te lo robaré para un proyecto pesonal, puedo? :D

Comment: claro o hay problema, al contrario, pero si me echas una mano a resolver mi duda te lo gradezco :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas calcular la mitad del documento para comparar con el desplazamiento actual. Puedes usar [document.body.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) para obtener la altura total y dividir entre 2.

No necesitas una función ni variable adicionales para aplicar el cambio entre visible y no visible, puedes usar la [lista de clases del elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#m%C3%A9todos) para saber si tiene o no la clase y, dependiendo el caso, agregarla o quitarla.

Otra mejora que puedes hacer es agregar los estilos directamente en una hoja CSS. En caso de no ser posible, agrega la etiqueta directamente en `<head>`, que es donde corresponde:

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<style>/* Aquí los estilos */</style>');
```

En el fragmento de código, el elemento parece mostrarse un poco después de que se ha superado el 50% de desplazamiento y se puede ajustar restando un número determinado; según las pruebas que hice aquí mismo, con -250 se ve bien:

```
let mitad = Math.floor(document.body.offsetHeight / 2) - 250;
```

Ya dependerá de ti si quieres ajustarlo y en qué cantidad.

```js
var todossticky = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

todossticky.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div id="stickyHome" class="sticky-container"><div class="button-primary-sticky content-item "><a id="a" href="#ancla1" target="_self" aria-label="Ver" title="Ver">Ver</a></div></div>');

let lastScrollY = 0, stickyHomeDisplayed = false;
  
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
    // Obtener altura total y dividir entre 2
    let mitad = Math.floor(document.body.offsetHeight / 2);
    // Obtener elemento
    let stickyHome = document.getElementById('stickyHome');

    // El scroll es igual o mayor a 50%
    if(window.scrollY >= mitad) {
        // Verificar que no está visible
        if(!stickyHome.classList.contains('visible')) {
            stickyHome.classList.toggle('visible');
        }
    } else if(stickyHomeDisplayed) {
        stickyHome.classList.toggle('visible');
    }
}, { passive: true });
```

```css
.button-primary-sticky {
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: orange;
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 44px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    min-width: 128px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: orange;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: orange;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease; cursor: pointer;
}
.button-primary-sticky a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#stickyHome.sticky-container.visible { bottom: 0px; }
#stickyHome.sticky-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -60px;
    height: auto;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
/*
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #stickyHome.sticky-container {display: none;}
}
*/
```

```html
<div style="height:2500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Funciona a la perfección. Un abrazo